# ACS ACR122U LED/Buzzer settings

Tags: nfc, rfid, apdu, smartcard-reader, acr122

I'm having issues trying to set the LED and buzzer using APDUs on an ACR122U (firmware version 2.1.5).

This command should set the Buzzer Output for Card Detection, but I always get an error response:

```
> FF 00 52 00 00 
< 63 00
```

Also, when trying to use one of the examples from the official documentation (v [2.04](https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/419/API-ACR122U-2.04.pdf)), I don't get the expected behavior, and the wrong response code (should be `90 02`):

```
> FF 00 40 50 04 05 05 03 01 
< 90 03
```

Other commands, like reading the firmware version, work as expected:

```
> FF 00 48 00 00 
< 41 43 52 31 32 32 55 32 31 35
```

Has anyone had the same issues before?

Answer (score 0):

#### Buzzer Output for Card Detection

I have two older versions of this reader here that do not seem to have a buzzer. Both of these readers always return `63 00` for that command. I'm not quite sure why this command might fail on versions that do have a buzzer though. However, looking at diffferent versions of the ACR122U API documentation, this command was only added in later versions of the reader.

#### Bi-color LED and Buzzer Control

The status code that you receive will only reflect the current state of the LEDs after you set the final state of the LEDs at least once. E.g. to set the final state off:

```
FF 00 40 0C 04 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: Yes, it does have a buzzer as I hear it when it detects a card.